# How to get all url's image from a multiple input file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get all url values from a multiple input file. It works correctly with just one image but if I try to attach more than one, I retrieve a null response and only get the last one correctly. I hope anybody could help with this issue!
Post my code below and JSFiddle example:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
            //show url image
          var dataURL = reader.result;
          alert(dataURL);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3q49moyj/

Comment: You're using `var reader`, which means it keeps getting overwritten. Use `let reader` instead.

Comment: What do you want to do with these urls? Chances are you don't even need a FileReader and that all you want is `[...files].map(URL.createObjectURL)`.